# How to register data in the notification from the database?

Tags: android, notifications

I make a simple reminder application that writes data to the database (SQLite).

How do I pull a note title a notification?

What to write in *.setContentText*?

**Class ReminderService:**

```
 @Override
 void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
  Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

  NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class);
  notificationIntent.putExtra(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


  Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
          .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
          .setContentTitle("Title")

          **.setContentText(???????????????????)**

          .setContentIntent(pi);
  Notification note = builder.build();
  note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
  note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  int id = (int)((long)rowId);
  mgr.notify(id, note);
 }
 }
```

Help me, please!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to query in SQLite?

Comment: yes, 
I need to get out the title

Comment: You only get the rowId back and not the actual text/title that you want to display. Currently the title is set to `Title` and the contentText will return null.

Comment: you should setContentText with pi variable. I mean use .setContentText(pi)